# Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number' in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have below code in my typescript file but when i compile this then it is giving me error like

**Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number'**

Thanks..

Here is my Code

```
this.languages.forEach((o: any, i: any) => {
                const control1 = new FormControl(this.UserSelectedLanguages.indexOf(o.id) > -1); // if first item set to true, else false
                (this.languageform.controls.selectedlang as FormArray).push(control1);
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to set a default value in control1 (true or false) ?

Comment: what's the type of `this.UserSelectedLanguages` anyway?

Comment: in ```this.UserSelectedLanguages``` i am getting array like ["1","2","3"] and i have to check that my ```o.id``` is in or not.

Comment: Try using this.UserSelectedLanguages.includes(o.id)

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry..  this.UserSelectedLanguages.includes(o.id) is also not working for me..and i could not create any minimal example.

Comment: I have created a simple implementation of indexOf based on your requirement. See if it helps you in any way : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctbow5

Comment: Thank you so much..i have edited that with my criteria but still i am getting Absent alert. Means  indexOf could not matched that ids.

Comment: Yes that means it is giving you the desired result. Right? Its allowing you to compare IndexOf with -1 whereas you were unable to compare that as per your question. Its telling you whether language is already present in userSelectedLanguage variable

Comment: Yes Right. But when i compile this then it is giving me same error in terminal.

Comment: Please Use  `UserSelectedLanguages = ["1","2"]` instead of `UserSelectedLanguages = [1]`.

Comment: what is `this.languages`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: ``this.languages = [
{"id":"3","name":"English"},
{"id":"2","name":"French"},
{"id":"1","name":"Italian"}
]``

Comment: I have strict mode enabled in my compiler and I did not get an error like that, so unless you can reproduce it, it will be hard to help. You have some sort of typing issue somewhere, probably how you have declared some data. We really need a mcve to help.

Comment: I have updated the stackblitz and created a Form Control based on your syntax. Click the Edit button and check the console. You will find 2 controls created one with value true and one with value false. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctbow5

Comment: it is unbelievable i have tried your code in my code but still i am getting this error in terminal but this code compiled successfully and also it working in site. but why i am getting this error in Terminal?..Thank you so much for your response and i appreciate your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers..

i got problems solution using this..

i have put `this.UserSelectedLanguages.indexOf(o.id) !== -1` instead of `this.UserSelectedLanguages.indexOf(o.id) > -1` and my problem solved..

Answer (score 4):

Having given this a bit more thought it occurs to me that the whole point of typescript is static typing, so trying to treat the return from `indexOf` as a boolean goes against the very thing TS is about.

Further, it's not clear to me how `indexOf` would return `void` in the first place. Is `UserSelectedLanguages` a regular js array?

I'm not that familiar with angular or typescript, but it looks like `this.UserSelectedLanguages.indexOf(o.id)` returns `void`, and you can't do a greater-than comparison between void and a number. If that's the case, you don't actually have to compare it to anything. Its mere non-void presence indicates it's there:

```js
// this alone may resolve to true or false
!!this.UserSelectedLanguages.indexOf(o.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..But it is giving me error like "An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness"..

Comment: Updated my answer with a better potential solution. Though attempting to cast `void` to a boolean may produce a similar error. Not sure how TS works on this stuff.

Comment: Right. After I posted that it occurred to me that the whole point of TS is static typing, so trying to cast void to a boolean goes against the very thing TS does. I'd suggest looking at the TS docs or searching for how to cast or convert void to a boolean in TS.

Comment: More evidence that I don't know what I'm talking about: Why does `indexOf` return void? Is `UserSelectedLanguages` an array? And doesn't `indexOf` always return either the index or -1? It's not clear to me how you'd be getting void from this expression. Is it possible that `UserSelectedLanguages` is void? Does TS offer protection for invoking a method on void?

Comment: ```indexOf``` return -1 if that could not find any number from array. and also i did not declare ```UserSelectedLanguages``` as an array. it is possible that without declaration it will take automaticaly void?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `this.UserSelectedLanguages` is actually an `array`, cause it seems that it's not.

Moreover a quick dirty solution would be to do something like this.

```
const control1 = new FormControl(<number>this.UserSelectedLanguages.indexOf(o.id) > -1);
```

Comment: it is giving me error like ```this.UserSelectedLanguages``` is not an function..and also not working.

Comment: try this `<number>(this.UserSelectedLanguages.indexOf(o.id))`

Comment: Sorry Not Working